# Can I create a Link style connection to an external OBJ file?

Tags: import

I would like to create some parts in FreeCAD or other software and Export as OBJ. STL or other files to render in Blender. But I would like to create a Link so that if I update the files, the mesh data in Blender would update, that way I wouldn't have to reassign materials, modifiers or redo any animation.

I've done something similar between AutoCAD and 3Ds, I wonder if its possible here.

Thanks.

Comment: AutoCAD and 3Ds are both Autodesk applications with native builtin intercommunication tools; such thing is not available in Blender as far as I know. Be smart about it. Put your imported objects in groups and instance those groups, parent the objects to empties and animate them instead, use armatures and link modifiers on updates. Not much you can do about materials though